# Testing promises with angularjs order of execution confusion

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, promise, q

I'm testing a promise with angularjs jasmine, and sinonjs.
I'm puzzled by something regarding promises. Here is my code:

```
it('should return data with length 4 ', inject(function ($rootScope) {              
  var storageData;

  mockDualStorage.getData.returns($.when(''));
  // mockDualStorage.getData is called by getStorageData

  // $rootScope.$digest() // not working here

  dataGetter.getStorageData().then(function (data) {
    console.log(1);
    storageData = data;
  });

  $rootScope.$digest(); // only working here

  console.log(2);
  expect(storageData.length).toBe(4)// ok

  }));
```

Couple of things are strange here.

If I put `$rootScope.$digest()` above the `dataGetter.getStorageData()` `then` function  is never executed.

- When the `$rootScope.$digest()` is below, `then` gets executed, and order of `console.log` is 1,2
- Why won't `then` execute when `$rootScope.$digest()` is above? As I understand promise is already resolved?

Comment: I suspect the `then` callback isn't properly closed with a `})` in your answer. Can you fix? Also, can you expand the example a bit, showing the surrounding/earlier function, where `$rootScope` is injected? It seems strange the `$rootScope` is defined when it's not in a `beforeEach`, `it` or `afterEach` block.

Comment: Everything is properly closed and injected in to the test.
My question is why is the promise working only **after** I register `then` callback?
According to promise specification attaching `then` to a resolved promise should be immediately executed.

Comment: I've edited the question to tidy up the placement of `})`, as it looked like they closed the function defined on the top line, and not the `then` callback. (If I've misunderstood, of course feel free to change it)

Answer (score 0):

After more carefully reading the documentation, found the answer right there.

> Differences between Kris Kowal's Q and $q : 
>   There are two main differences: $q is integrated with the $rootScope.Scope Scope model observation mechanism in angular, which means faster propagation of resolution or rejection into your models and avoiding unnecessary browser repaints, which would result in flickering UI.

[AngularJS $q service documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)